# Read from a very large databse in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a database table with over a million records
in my views, i select all records like below:

```
data=Student.objects.all()
```

I get a memory error when rendering the result to a grid on the template.
Any good practise to run large querysets without error please?
Regards
Joshua

Comment: And why would you want to render 1 million rows at once? Have a look at pagination.

Comment: Make sure you have `DEBUG = False` in your `settings.py`.

Comment: I have debug off but that would'nt work..

Comment: Hi tony, can i use pagination on queryset?

Comment: Sure, take a look at this pattern https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/pagination/#using-paginator-in-a-view

Comment: I am using jqwidgets in the front end which defines its own pagination.this prevents me from using pagination on the template!!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet so I'll just post this as an answer. You might want to consider using 
[jquery datatable](http://datatables.net/index) for front end UI. It has [server side processing](http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html) option which is ideal for dealing with large database. Just a suggestion.